# Python boxplot matplotlib automatic figure size based on the number of categories

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to use matplotlib to show and save a boxplot chart.

But the number of categories is variable, so that, I cannot have a fixed figsize and the figure size (canvas area) must be adjusted based on number of categories.

I'm struggling to get this working in a dynamic fashion.

When I have just a few categories the chart is ok, but the case below (131 categories) I'm getting the following chart:

[image]

So, I imagine that I should, somehow, set the size of a single box (or a placeholder for an empty serie) and then the chart grows based on the box_size * number_of_classes.

Below some code I tried.

```
f = plt.figure()
# f = plt.figure(figsize=(len(classes) * 2, 50))

# Create an axes instance
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

## add patch_artist=True option to ax.boxplot() 
## to get fill color
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, patch_artist=True)

## change outline color, fill color and linewidth of the boxes
for box in bp['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set( color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)
    # change fill color
    box.set( facecolor = '#1b9e77' )

## change color and linewidth of the whiskers
for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)

## change color and linewidth of the caps
for cap in bp['caps']:
    cap.set(color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)

## change color and linewidth of the medians
for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color='#b2df8a', linewidth=2)

## change the style of fliers and their fill
for flier in bp['fliers']:
    flier.set(marker='o', color='#e7298a', alpha=0.5)

## Custom x-axis labels
ax.set_xticklabels(classes)

## Remove top axes and right axes ticks
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()        

if boxplot_output is not None:
    os.makedirs(boxplot_output, exist_ok=True)
    f.savefig(os.path.join(boxplot_output,'box_plot.png'), bbox_inches='tight')

if show:
    plt.show()
    plt.close(f)
```

How could I get it working ?

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the left and right margin in inches. Choose how large in inches you want one single category to display. Then the complete figure width is

```
figwidth = leftmargin + rightmargin + (n+1)*categorysize
```

Then don't forget to adjust the subplot parameters depending on the figure size.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

number = 10
data = np.random.rayleigh(scale=30, size=(20, number))


leftmargin = 0.5 #inches
rightmargin = 0.3 #inches
categorysize = 0.1 # inches

n = data.shape[1]

figwidth = leftmargin + rightmargin + (n+1)*categorysize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(figwidth, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=leftmargin/figwidth, right=1-rightmargin/figwidth,
                    top=0.94, bottom=0.1)

ax.boxplot(data, positions=np.arange(n))
ax.set_xlim(-0.5,n-0.5)

plt.show()
```

For number=10:

[image]

For number=42

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import seaborn as sns
# load the dataset
dt = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

# display 5 rows of dataset
dt.head() 

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(13.7,8.27)}) #set width and height

dt.boxplot(by ='row_name', column =['column_name'], grid=False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).