# Python confusion matrix matplotlib automatic figure size based on the number of categories

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following function to generate a confusion matrix:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes, normalize=False, cmap=cm.Blues, png_output=None, show=True):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        title='Normalized confusion matrix'
    else:
        title='Confusion matrix'

    f = plt.figure()

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                horizontalalignment="center",
                color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    if png_output is not None:
        os.makedirs(png_output, exist_ok=True)
        f.savefig(os.path.join(png_output,'confusion_matrix.png'), bbox_inches='tight')

    if show:
        plt.show()
        plt.close(f)
    else:
        plt.close(f)
```

When I have a few classes I get a neat chart like this one:

[image]

But when I have a large number of classes I get this:

[image]

I tried to use the same approach as used on this solution [Python boxplot matplotlib automatic figure size based on the number of categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756558/python-boxplot-matplotlib-automatic-figure-size-based-on-the-number-of-categorie/54756766#54756766) but it didn't work.

How can I have my confusion matrix adjusting its size based on the number of classes like in the boxplot solution above ?

**UPDATE 1**

After including the ticks position and dynamic figwidth

[image]

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred, classes, normalize=False, cmap=cm.Blues, png_output=None, show=True):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        title='Normalized confusion matrix'
    else:
        title='Confusion matrix'

    # Calculate chart area size
    leftmargin = 0.5 # inches
    rightmargin = 0.5 # inches
    categorysize = 0.5 # inches
    figwidth = leftmargin + rightmargin + (len(classes) * categorysize)           

    f = plt.figure(figsize=(figwidth, figwidth))

    # Create an axes instance and ajust the subplot size
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    f.subplots_adjust(left=leftmargin/figwidth, right=1-rightmargin/figwidth, top=0.94, bottom=0.1)

    res = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)

    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar(res)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(classes)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(classes)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(classes, rotation=45, ha='right')
    ax.set_yticklabels(classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                horizontalalignment="center",
                color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    # plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    if png_output is not None:
        os.makedirs(png_output, exist_ok=True)
        f.savefig(os.path.join(png_output,'confusion_matrix.png'), bbox_inches='tight')

    if show:
        plt.show()
        plt.close(f)
    else:
        plt.close(f)
```

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Which code did you try that failed?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I deleted the code :(. But in the other approach you used a subplot. In this case as there is no 'plot type' being used, such as boxplot, I didn't realize how to transform this code to work as subplot.

Comment: The plot type you use here is `.imshow`. Else, it's really the same. The three  differences are that (1) here you would use `n` instead of `n+1`, (2) You have a colorbar, which you could additionally account for, (3) you would need to perform this operation for both horizontal (`width`, `left`, `right`) and vertical (`height`, `top`, `bottom`). I guess you can ignore (1) and (2) for the moment, the changes are pretty small.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest struggling to get this working. I've just posted what I could do after many hours googling and trying :(. May you help on that ?

Comment: It's not too bad. One problem you have is that you only set the ticklabels, but not the tick positions, hence the labels are wrong.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried it before including ax.set_xticks(range(len(classes))) and ax.set_yticks(range(len(classes))), but I got the same wrong chart as we see on the first message. the only difference is that the labels now are aligned with the ticks.

Comment: I guess it's just wrong on screen?! If you save the image it should be correct?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest see the "UPDATE 1" in the original image. Was saved using savefig(). I didn't figure out yet how to grow the squares to fit perfectly in the chart area.

Comment: In that case you have more classes than combinations in `y_true,y_pred`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes :( Looks like that I have a bug in my code. After I fix that hopefully the new code will work as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just adjusting the figsize in plt.figure?

Comment: @JodyKlymak No. It was a bug in my code where I had more classes than y_true/y_pred combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the correct chart now with @ImportanceOfBeingErnest helps.

[image]

Below the final code:

```
   def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes, normalize=False, cmap=cm.Blues, png_output=None, show=True):
        """
        This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
        Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
        """
        if normalize:
            cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
            title='Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title='Confusion matrix'

        # Calculate chart area size
        leftmargin = 0.5 # inches
        rightmargin = 0.5 # inches
        categorysize = 0.5 # inches
        figwidth = leftmargin + rightmargin + (len(classes) * categorysize)           

        f = plt.figure(figsize=(figwidth, figwidth))

        # Create an axes instance and ajust the subplot size
        ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_aspect(1)
        f.subplots_adjust(left=leftmargin/figwidth, right=1-rightmargin/figwidth, top=0.94, bottom=0.1)

        res = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)

        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar(res)
        ax.set_xticks(range(len(classes)))
        ax.set_yticks(range(len(classes)))
        ax.set_xticklabels(classes, rotation=45, ha='right')
        ax.set_yticklabels(classes)

        fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    horizontalalignment="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

        # plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

        if png_output is not None:
            os.makedirs(png_output, exist_ok=True)
            f.savefig(os.path.join(png_output,'confusion_matrix.png'), bbox_inches='tight')

        if show:
            plt.show()
            plt.close(f)
        else:
            plt.close(f)
```